# How to pluralize 2 words

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms, compound-nouns

I have an organisation which has several branches. Now I have a list of all these branch names. How can I call this list?

**Branches name** list? or **Branch Names** list? or **Branches Names** list?

What is the rule for pluralizing compound words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance you are talking about **The list of branch names**, so the best title would be the **Branch Names List**.

Because you are choosing a title and there is no grammar involved, either of the other two might serve your purpose - but they don't fit the role comfortably.

While the pluralising of compound nouns is always tricky, there are helpful guides online :

https://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-plural-compound-nouns.php